# Python: Threading specific number of times

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have the following code that uses `threading` and prints the current count.

```
import threading

count = 0
def worker():
    """thread worker function"""
    global count
    count += 1
    print(count)

threads = []
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

It is currently set to 5 threads. How can I have it continue running the threads until it reaches a certain #. i.e. run at 5 threads until `worker()` has run 100 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just do a while loop, but protect your counter and your test with a lock, otherwise the value tested will be different from the one you just increased.

I have added the thread id so we see which thread is actually increasing the counter.

Also: check first, increase after.

And wait for the threads in the end.

```
import threading

lck = threading.Lock()

count = 0
def worker():
    global count
    """thread worker function"""
    while True:
        lck.acquire()
        if count==100:
            lck.release()
            break
        count += 1
        print(threading.current_thread() ,count)
        lck.release()

threads = []
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

result:

```
(<Thread(Thread-1, started 5868)>, 1)
(<Thread(Thread-2, started 7152)>, 2)
(<Thread(Thread-3, started 6348)>, 3)
(<Thread(Thread-4, started 6056)>, 4)
(<Thread(Thread-1, started 5868)>, 5)
(<Thread(Thread-5, started 5748)>, 6)
(<Thread(Thread-2, started 7152)>, 7)
(<Thread(Thread-3, started 6348)>, 8)
(<Thread(Thread-4, started 6056)>, 9)
(<Thread(Thread-1, started 5868)>, 10)
(<Thread(Thread-5, started 5748)>, 11)
(<Thread(Thread-2, started 7152)>, 12)
(<Thread(Thread-3, started 6348)>, 13)
(<Thread(Thread-4, started 6056)>, 14)
(<Thread(Thread-1, started 5868)>, 15)
(<Thread(Thread-5, started 5748)>, 16)
(<Thread(Thread-2, started 7152)>, 17)
(<Thread(Thread-3, started 6348)>, 18)
(<Thread(Thread-4, started 6056)>, 19)
(<Thread(Thread-1, started 5868)>, 20)
(<Thread(Thread-5, started 5748)>, 21)
(<Thread(Thread-2, started 7152)>, 22)
(<Thread(Thread-3, started 6348)>, 23)
(<Thread(Thread-4, started 6056)>, 24)
(<Thread(Thread-1, started 5868)>, 25)
(<Thread(Thread-5, started 5748)>, 26)
(<Thread(Thread-2, started 7152)>, 27)
(<Thread(Thread-3, started 6348)>, 28)
(<Thread(Thread-4, started 6056)>, 29)
(<Thread(Thread-1, started 5868)>, 30)
(<Thread(Thread-5, started 5748)>, 31)
(<Thread(Thread-2, started 7152)>, 32)
(<Thread(Thread-3, started 6348)>, 33)
(<Thread(Thread-4, started 6056)>, 34)
(<Thread(Thread-1, started 5868)>, 35)
(<Thread(Thread-5, started 5748)>, 36)
(<Thread(Thread-2, started 7152)>, 37)
(<Thread(Thread-3, started 6348)>, 38)
(<Thread(Thread-4, started 6056)>, 39)
(<Thread(Thread-1, started 5868)>, 40)
(<Thread(Thread-5, started 5748)>, 41)
(<Thread(Thread-2, started 7152)>, 42)
(<Thread(Thread-3, started 6348)>, 43)
(<Thread(Thread-4, started 6056)>, 44)
(<Thread(Thread-1, started 5868)>, 45)
(<Thread(Thread-5, started 5748)>, 46)
(<Thread(Thread-2, started 7152)>, 47)
(<Thread(Thread-3, started 6348)>, 48)
(<Thread(Thread-4, started 6056)>, 49)
(<Thread(Thread-1, started 5868)>, 50)
(<Thread(Thread-5, started 5748)>, 51)
(<Thread(Thread-2, started 7152)>, 52)
(<Thread(Thread-3, started 6348)>, 53)
(<Thread(Thread-4, started 6056)>, 54)
(<Thread(Thread-1, started 5868)>, 55)
(<Thread(Thread-5, started 5748)>, 56)
(<Thread(Thread-2, started 7152)>, 57)
(<Thread(Thread-3, started 6348)>, 58)
(<Thread(Thread-4, started 6056)>, 59)
(<Thread(Thread-1, started 5868)>, 60)
(<Thread(Thread-5, started 5748)>, 61)
(<Thread(Thread-2, started 7152)>, 62)
(<Thread(Thread-3, started 6348)>, 63)
(<Thread(Thread-4, started 6056)>, 64)
(<Thread(Thread-1, started 5868)>, 65)
(<Thread(Thread-5, started 5748)>, 66)
(<Thread(Thread-2, started 7152)>, 67)
(<Thread(Thread-3, started 6348)>, 68)
(<Thread(Thread-4, started 6056)>, 69)
(<Thread(Thread-1, started 5868)>, 70)
(<Thread(Thread-5, started 5748)>, 71)
(<Thread(Thread-2, started 7152)>, 72)
(<Thread(Thread-3, started 6348)>, 73)
(<Thread(Thread-4, started 6056)>, 74)
(<Thread(Thread-1, started 5868)>, 75)
(<Thread(Thread-5, started 5748)>, 76)
(<Thread(Thread-2, started 7152)>, 77)
(<Thread(Thread-3, started 6348)>, 78)
(<Thread(Thread-4, started 6056)>, 79)
(<Thread(Thread-1, started 5868)>, 80)
(<Thread(Thread-5, started 5748)>, 81)
(<Thread(Thread-2, started 7152)>, 82)
(<Thread(Thread-3, started 6348)>, 83)
(<Thread(Thread-4, started 6056)>, 84)
(<Thread(Thread-1, started 5868)>, 85)
(<Thread(Thread-5, started 5748)>, 86)
(<Thread(Thread-2, started 7152)>, 87)
(<Thread(Thread-3, started 6348)>, 88)
(<Thread(Thread-4, started 6056)>, 89)
(<Thread(Thread-1, started 5868)>, 90)
(<Thread(Thread-5, started 5748)>, 91)
(<Thread(Thread-2, started 7152)>, 92)
(<Thread(Thread-3, started 6348)>, 93)
(<Thread(Thread-4, started 6056)>, 94)
(<Thread(Thread-1, started 5868)>, 95)
(<Thread(Thread-5, started 5748)>, 96)
(<Thread(Thread-2, started 7152)>, 97)
(<Thread(Thread-3, started 6348)>, 98)
(<Thread(Thread-4, started 6056)>, 99)
(<Thread(Thread-1, started 5868)>, 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop it, of course.

```
lock = threading.Lock()
count = 0
def worker():
    """thread worker function"""
    global count
    while True:
        with lock:
            if count >= 100: break
            count += 1
            print(count)
```

Notice the protected access to `count` with `threading.Lock`; relying on [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock) is sketchy.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, if you want something like this, it means that you are going to wrong direction. Because this code is `stateful` and `stateful` processing is far away from real parallel execution.
Also usually if you want to execute code in parallel in python, you need to use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

So, basically, if you goal is to tick 100 times in total, it's better to rewrite your code in stateless way:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker_1(x):
  for i in range(x)
      print i

def worker_2(y):
   print y

if __name__ == '__main__':
  p = mp.Pool(5)

  for x in p.pool(worker_1, [25, 25, 25, 25]):
     // process result
     pass

  for y in p.pool(worker_2, range(100)):
     // process result
     pass
```